# ASP.NET CORE with JavaScriptServices and Angular material 2

Tags: asp.net-core, angular-material2

I start the tutorial on:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/

It is really awesome until i start to add Angular 2 material component.
I import the angular material 2 in the app.module.ts:

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
 import { UniversalModule } from 'angular2-universal';
 import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component'
 import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
 import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
 import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
 import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';    
 import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';

 @NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        UniversalModule, // Must be first import. This automatically imports BrowserModule, HttpModule, and JsonpModule too.
        MaterialModule.forRoot(),
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
            { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

I just want to add a tab:

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
    <md-tab-group>
        <md-tab label="One">
            <h1>Some tab content</h1>
            <p>...</p>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="Two">
            <h1>Some more tab content</h1>
            <p>...</p>
        </md-tab>
    </md-tab-group>
</div>
```

I get this error:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: ReferenceError:
>   window is not defined at new ScrollDispatcher
>   (C:\sources\testAngularCore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:6701:46) at
>   SCROLL_DISPATCHER_PROVIDER_FACTORY
>   (C:\sources\testAngularCore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:6772:32) at
>   AppModuleInjector.get (/AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:210:77) at
>   AppModuleInjector.get (/AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:215:155) at
>   AppModuleInjector.getInternal (/AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:529:53)
>   at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get
>   (C:\sources\testAngularCore\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:8563:48) at
>   CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.injectorGet
>   (C:\sources\testAngularCore\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:12008:49) at
>   CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_MdTabHeader0.createInternal
>   (/MdTabsModule/MdTabHeader/component.ngfactory.js:19:157) at
>   CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.create
>   (C:\sources\testAngularCore\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:11951:25) at
>   CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_MdTabGroup0.createInternal
>   (/MdTabsModule/MdTabGroup/component.ngfactory.js:299:19) at
>   CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.create
>   (C:\sources\testAngularCore\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:11951:25) at
>   CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppComponent0.createInternal
>   (/AppModule/AppComponent/component.ngfactory.js:52:19) at
>   CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.create
>   (C:\sources\testAngularCore\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:11951:25) at
>   CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal
>   (/AppModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:15:19) at
>   CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.createHostView
>   (C:\sources\testAngularCore\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:11964:25)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.HttpNodeInstance+d__7.MoveNext()

Cannot import hammerjs as well.
Anyone can explain me ?
Thanks!

Comment: What version of angular are you using?

Comment: Lose those `forRoot()` calls on router and material. And read up on paths. https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/child_routes.html

Comment: Yes I tried without the forRoot() and i still have the problem.

Comment: the version of angular: 2.4.10

Comment: I'm seeing several things that are related to hammerjs as the main cause for this error.  Try adding `@types/hammerjs` to your main package.json section, then `hammerjs` to your development section of package.json.  If this fails, you can find a CDN of hammerjs and just link it in your main page (_layout.cshtml or whatever)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error is indicating a problem with the server side rendering of of some component that is trying access the window object, probably from material, which isn't fully instantiated on the server.  I delt with this by disabling server side rendering  in Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
@*<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>*@
<app>Loading...</app>
<script src="~/dist/vendor.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/dist/main-client.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

Also,

Make sure you add this to package.json

```
 "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
```

Then you need to add the material css to the webpack config and invoke webpack manually.
In vendor.config add

```
 entry: {
            vendor: [
                '@angular/common',
                '@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css',
```

then run

```
webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js
webpack
```

in the root app folder to invoke webpack.